# How to link libssh library in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, libssh

I get following error, when i tried to compile my test program

```
g++     main.cpp   -o main
/tmp/ccICBwKO.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `ssh_new'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `ssh_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

In my make file i have:

```
all:        main

$main:  main.cpp
        g++ main.cpp -o main -lssh
```

Thanks for help. (I really hate C/C++...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the log, `make` is not using the rule you have given for `$main`. I suspect that you want to name it either `main` or `$(main)`.

`$main` concatenates the value of variable `$m` (defaults to nothing as `m` is not defined) with `ain`, so that you've created a rule for `ain` instead of `main`. `make` thus rely on its default rules for creating an executable from a `.cpp` file, which does not include linking with `libssh`.

Comment: Perfectly right. The makefile can be fixed by removing the leading $ in the Makefile. This is not a libssh-related problem by the way.